# Is it possible to change the step template when using Cucumber-groovy?

Tags: groovy, cucumber

I am just started with cucumber-groovy. One thing I find awkward is that cucumber-groovy generates templates like

```
When(~'^some number is larger than (\\d)$') { int arg1 ->
...
}
```

where the awkward bit is the use of the single quotes. I mean, why not like this:

```
When( /^some number is larger than (\d)$/ ) { int arg1 ->
...
}
```

This way you don't have to escape the backslash, which makes the pattern more readable, IMHO. So, is it possible to make cucumber-groovy generate the step templates like that in an easy way?

Thank you very much.